# Sanity check: why is there a gap between vertical lines drawn using Graphics.drawLine at x and x+1?

Tags: java, swing, draw, graphics2d

I was surprised when I found there exists a gap between two vertical lines drawn at `x` and `x+1` using `myGraphics.drawLine(x,someY,x,someOtherY)`. My canvas is a `JPanel` with an overridden `paintComponent(Graphics)`.

1. Why is this and how to prevent it?

Here's a screenshot of the gap:
[image: image showing two lines separated by a gap]

**Code**

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class rough {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        var pn=new JPanel(){
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics gg) {
                super.paintComponent(gg);
                var g=(Graphics2D)gg;

                var x=10;
                var h=getHeight();
                g.drawLine(x,0,x,h);
                x+=1;
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawLine(x,0,x,h);

            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(200,200);
            }
        };

        var fr=new JFrame(LocalTime.now().toString());
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.getContentPane().add(pn);
        fr.pack();
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Env:**
OpenJDK 16
Windows 20H2
Display scaling: 150% (motivated by @Pshemo's comment)
Screen resolution: 1920 by 1080

Comment: What is your OS? Did you set some OS scaling options? (I could reproduce your problem on Windows 10 with 150% scaling but with 100% scaling problem seems to disappear)

Comment: @Pshemo yep, its a scaling artifact, at least on windows...went back and forth between 100% & 150% and the gap disappears/reappears...may you try on other OS' ? I'll accept if you post. thnx!

Comment: Sorry, can't test on other OS. Anyway form what I heard problems with scaling ware one reasons people moved from `swing` to `JavaFX` (even if it is not part of standard Java).

Comment: Check your stroke size. "Display scaling: 150%" is your answer. One pixel in user space is approximately 1,5 pixels in screen space for you case. In this particular situation swing decided that it would skip a screen-pixel (as 1,5 pixels necessitate rounding).

Comment: @weisj thnx for going into the specifics (Pshemo had also pointed to display scaling being the culprit)